# Maximum number of user per cluster in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

We are trying to create multiple users for our redshift cluster to implement WLM. can anyone please tell us what is the maximum number of users supported by redshift per cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know the actual limit number of users, I confirmed more than 10,000 users can be created on a Redshift cluster.

```
dev=# select count(*) from pg_user;
count
-------
10003
(1 row)
```